# Save and Open document files in Shared folder in Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: xamarin, windows-phone-8.1

In my Windows Phone 8.1 + WIndows Store 8.1 app, need to download the file and save to some shared location. Then need to open the same file so, user can select/open through suitable native/installed app.

Example: I can download  .pdf and then give command to open this file in Adobe Acrobat/user provided app.

Downloading to LocalFolder and RoamingFolder works fine, but while opening it gives access denied error.

```
StorageFolder local = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
var file = await local.CreateFileAsync(fileName,, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting); 
stream.Position = 0;
stream.CopyTo(await file.OpenStreamForWriteAsync());
return file.Path;
```

Later, following funciton is getting called to open the downloaded document  from above code

```
Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri(fileName));
```

Please let me know, how to save files to any shared folder or permission to make it accessible to another app and open. Thanks in advance.

Please note, although the answer will not differ, I'm using this in native Windows App solution inside Xamarin. I've implemented similar funcitonality in Android native, which works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Later I found that the access denied error was not due to Local or Roaming folder, but was because the file was kept opened by code while creating.

So the code was replaced as:

```
StorageFolder local = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
var file = await local.CreateFileAsync(fileName, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting); 
stream.Position = 0;
using (Stream fileStream = await file.OpenStreamForWriteAsync())
        {
            stream.CopyTo(fileStream);
        }
return file.Path;
```

and also to open the file from app, replaced the code with:

```
StorageFile fileToLaunch = await StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(fileName);
bool done = await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchFileAsync(fileToLaunch, new Windows.System.LauncherOptions { DisplayApplicationPicker = true });
```

Thank you.